# Left-align X-axis label with first tick text on X-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

Considering the following example,

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(number = c(5, 10, 11 ,12,12,12,13,15,15))
ggplot(dat, aes(x = number)) + geom_histogram()
```

How can I left-align the label of X-axis in such a way to be aligned with the **text** of the first tick on X-axis?

The result should look like:
[image]

#### I am looking for a solution that can be easily generalized to other plots.

Comment: You need something more specific than what you get with `theme(axis.title.x = element_text(hjust = 0))`?

Comment: Yes, if you test your solution it will be clear the X-axis label is not aligned with the text of the first tick but it will be aligned with the origin of X-axis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We could get the position of the first tick labels once we create the plot object

```
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = number)) + 
                      geom_histogram()

i1 <- ggplot_build(p)$layout$panel_ranges[[1]]$x.major[1]
#or
library(magrittr)
i1 <-  p %>% 
          ggplot_build %>% 
          extract2("layout") %>%
          extract2("panel_ranges") %>%
          extract2(1) %>% 
          extract2("x.major") %>%
          extract(1)
```

and then use that in `theme`.  Better would be take a look and adjust if it is necessary

```
p + 
   theme(axis.title.x = element_text(hjust = i1- 0.01))
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know what is your secret but you always have the answer for my questions. From now on, I will refer to you as the Oracle.